# stop a javascript canvas animation from looping

Tags: javascript, html, loops, animation, canvas

When the object collides with another object, I want it to only animate once, at the moment it animates fine the first time and then the second, third etc runs in the background all the time.

```
var imgEx = new Image();
imgEx.src = 'images/explosion.png';

var xpos = 0;
var ypos = 0;
var index = 0; 
var numFrames = 74; 
var frameSize = 100;

function explosion () {
xpos += frameSize;

index += 1;

if (index >= numFrames) {
xpos =0;
ypos =0;
index=0;    
return;             
} 
else if (xpos + frameSize > imgEx.width){
xpos =0;
ypos += frameSize;
}
}
```

this is wear I call the animation.

```
    Jet.prototype.checkEnemyCollision = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        if (this.drawX < enemies[i].drawX + enemies[i].width && this.drawX + this.width > enemies[i].drawX && this.drawY < enemies[i].drawY + enemies[i].height && this.drawY + this.height > enemies[i].drawY) {
            if (score > highScore) {
                highScore = score;
            }

            // Added the functions below, removed score = 0


            ctxGameOver.drawImage(imgEx, xpos, ypos, frameSize, frameSize, (jet1.drawX - 50), (jet1.drawY - 50), frameSize, frameSize);
            if (xpos < 800) {
                setInterval(explosion, 1000 / 74);
            }
            if (xpos === 800) {
                stopLoop();
                clearCtxGame();
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Basically I've made a game and when the jet hits an object it displays an animation and takes me to the game over screen, when I press play again the animation is already looping in the background and slowing the game down, if I happen to play the game 3 or 4 times in one go its running the loop 3/4 times in the background making the game terribly slow.

Comment: you do a set interval on the explosion, but since you don't store the interval handler, you cannot stop the setInterval, so all explosions will keep on exploding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following. Assign the interval to a variable, then clear it on game over.

```
    if (xpos < 800) {
            this.explosion = setInterval(explosion, 1000 / 74);
        }
        if (xpos === 800) {
            stopLoop();
            clearInterval(this.explosion);
            clearCtxGame();
            gameOver();
        }
```

Or a better approach in my opinion,

```
        if (xpos < 800) {
            explosion();
        }
```

Explosion function.

```
function explosion() {
    xpos += frameSize;

    index += 1;

    if (index >= numFrames) {
        xpos = 0;
        ypos = 0;
        index = 0;
        return;
    } else if (xpos + frameSize > imgEx.width) {
        xpos = 0;
        ypos += frameSize;
        setTimeout(explosion, 1000 / 74);
    }
}
```

So basically what happens is you call `explosion()`, and then let the `explosion()` function handle when it stops. If its done the `timeOut` wont be called and it'll stop on its own.